# Need help creating a function and error with switch statement

Tags: c++, c++11, switch-statement

I'm using a switch statement to process through some code, which I will create a function in my main to call. I'm having trouble with the switch quantity with my switch statement. Also, how would I create a function for these 10 cases? Very confused, any help greatly appreciated! Thanks! Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void constitution(); // the function that will call my amendments in my main function
                     // how will i create this will 10 possible amendments to choose from?
                     // There are 4 pirates and they will vote either yes or no,
int main()
{
  cout << "Below is a list of the 10 amendments that the two pirates will vote on  according to the ships constitution" << endl;
  string amendments = 0;
  cin >> amendments;    // selecting the amendment
  switch (amendments)
  { 
    // for outputting the amendment(s) voted on, which will
    // be passed on to a function in main to call
    case 1: cout << "What does the fox say? Whatever WE tell it to";  //case 1-10 are the 10 amendments to be voted on
            break;
    case 2: cout << "From now on the annual Cinco de Mayo party will be held on March 8th ";
            break;
    case 3: cout << "Beginning this year, sharks shall have a week dedicated to us";
            break;
    case 4: cout << "Pirates are now allowed to talk about fight club";
            break;
    case 5: cout << "When in Rome, the Romans will do as WE do.";
            break;
    case 6: cout << "Our mothers will immediately get tattoos that say SON";
            break;
    case 7: cout << "From now on the President will take our birthdays off.";
            break;
    case 8: cout << "If we say something costs an arm and a leg, it does";
            break;
    case 9: cout << "Freemasons are ordered to learn OUR secret handshake.";
            break;
    case 10: cout << "If a tree falls in the forest and no one is around, it will make a sound only with our permission ";
            break;
    default: cout << "This won't be used since a amendment will always be voted on, thus never be shown or checked I believe.. (Please correct me) ";
            break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make `amendments` an int and your switch should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to change is making amendments an integer, as switch expects an int.

```
int main()
{
  cout << "Below is a list of the 10 amendments that the two pirates will vote on  according to the ships constitution" << endl;
  int amendments = 0;
  cin >> amendments;    // selecting the amendment
  switch (amendments)
  { 

  ...
}
```

If you want to use amendments as a String, I am afraid you are not going to be able to check it via switch. Instead, you should use if/else if statements:

```
if(amendments == '1') {
   ...
} else if (amendments == '2') {
   ...
}
```